# Run Python 3.3 On My Webpage

Tags: cgi, html, python-3.3

For pure education reasoning, I would like to know how to run a Python 3.3 script similar to the one below. I know I need to rename it to `index.cgi`, and put it in `cgi-bin` what else do I do? I'm using Heliohost, so they are able to compile Python. I also put `file_name.txt` into `cgi-bin` too.

```
file=open('file_name.txt')
print(file.read())
print('We just read the file')
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

One thing is you have to make sure of is that the permissions allow the file to be executable by the web server user.

Usually:

```
# chmod 755 index.cgi
```